# expected identifier token '('

Tags: c, sockets

I am having trouble converting a hostname to a IP address for a ping version of traceroute (traceroute -I)

I beleive i may be incorrectly casting my pointer, i am trying to access sin_port of the sockaddr_in struct, and the s_addr of the in_addr struct.

```
struct addrinfo * addrptr

...call getaddrinfo an start scanning results

if(addrptr->ai_family == AF_INET
      && addrptr->(struct sockaddr_in *)ai_addr->sin_port == 0 
      && addrptr->(struct in_addr *)ai_addr->s_addr == INADDR_ANY){
```

the error occurs at:

```
               & addrptr->(struct sockaddr_in *)ai_addr->sin_port == 0 
                          ^
```

Comment: "expected identifier token '('" -- What was the actual error message? (The problem is that the right operand of `->` or `.` must be an identifier that's a member name; it's not an expression.)

Comment: i dont remember now, it was similar to the above. I have new problems now i beleive this one is solved.

Comment: Your question will be more useful to future readers if you can show the actual error message in the title or question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
((struct sockaddr_in *)(addrptr->ai_addr))->sin_port
((struct sockaddr_in *)(addrptr->ai_addr))->s_addr
```

Comment: Technically, you don't need the second set of parens - `->` is higher precedence than a cast.

Comment: Yeah. I tend to overuse them. I'm paranoid about it and I'd hate to have to debug some issue that is the result of a missing set of parenthesis.

Comment: It also makes it visually obvious what's happening in this example with the error.